# Убегающий ScrollBar на flowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

На форме(Windows Forms) есть flowLayoutPanel в который динамически добавляются разные элементы. AutoScroll = true. Количество элементов разное и зависит от выбора одного или нескольких уже созданных в панели. Есть полоса прокрутки но каждый раз при создании или обновлении контролов на flowLayoutPanel эта полоса уходит в начало списка. Есть ли простой способ запретить полосе прокрутки возвращаться в начало, иначе чем при выборе пользователя?

Comment: Перед добавлением нового элемента , запоминайте [AutoScrollOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.autoscrolloffset(v=vs.110).aspx) и выставляйте обратно после добавления